# How I can import the calculation from auxiliary classes to the main class by a String method?

Tags: java

I am new in java ... I just want to use an auxiliary class to calculate a bill for the car repair shop ... depending on the parts cost, working hours and a 20% vat. and we consider that the cost for the hour will be 20$. The bill will be calculated within the auxiliary class and the program will ask the user to enter the part cost and number of working hours. Please inform me

```
package Exs2Lecture7;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class CarRepairApp {

    private static String partsStr; 
    private static String hoursStr;
    private static double parts = Double.parseDouble(partsStr);
    private static double hours = Double.parseDouble(hoursStr);
    private static double bill;
    private static CarRepair myRepair;

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        CarRepair myRepair = new CarRepair(parts,hours);

        partsStr = read("Please enter the cost for the parts: ");
        hoursStr = read("Please enter the working hours: ");
    }

    public static String read (String prompt)
    {
        return (JOptionPane.showInputDialog(prompt));
    }
    public void display(String s)
    {
        this.bill = myRepair.calculateBill();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The cost for the bill will be " + bill);
    }

}
```

and the auxiliary class will be

```
package Exs2Lecture7;

import javax.swing.*;

public class CarRepair 

{

    private double parts;
    private double hours;
    private static double HOURS_COST = 20;
    private static double VAT = 20;


    public CarRepair(double p, double h)
    {
        parts = p;
        hours = h;
    }

    public double calculateBill()
    {
        /*double bill = (parts + (hours * HOURS_COST)) + 
                ((parts + (hours * HOURS_COST)) * VAT/100);*/
        return ((this.parts + (this.hours * HOURS_COST)) + 
                ((this.parts + (this.hours * HOURS_COST)) * VAT/100));


    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse string and convert them into double.

```
double partsDouble= Double.parseDouble(partsStr);
double hoursDouble= Double.parseDouble(hoursStr);
```

Then create an instance of `CarRepair` like

```
CarRepair carRepair = new CarRepair(partsDouble,hoursDouble);
```

then you can call calculateBill() method on it

```
carRepair.calculateBill();
```

**UPDATE**

Correctly pointed out by @Blip,no need to create another reference.
Change your main like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        partsStr = read("Please enter the cost for the parts: ");
        hoursStr = read("Please enter the working hours: ");
        double partsDouble= Double.parseDouble(partsStr);
        double hoursDouble= Double.parseDouble(hoursStr);
        myRepair = new CarRepair(partsDouble,hoursDouble);
        myRepair.display();//no need to pass anything
    }
```

Comment: In the code shared OP has already declared `CarRepair` as variable `myRepair` so what's the utility of creating a new instance of `CarRepair`?

Comment: updated my answer for clarity.

Comment: I feel you did not get my point. The OP has this `main` method in class `CarRepairApp`. The class `CarRepairApp` has already declared variable `myRepair` as static and of type `CarRepair`. So, I am asking you whether it is required that you again create another instance of `CarRepair`? Also If you used the variable `myRepair` then you will not be required to change the `display` method which uses `myRepair` variable.

Comment: Thanks @Blip for poinitng it out.Just missed that.

Comment: @Prince why we need (myRpair.display();)?  myRepair is an object for the class CarRepair